# how to submit the form with a different actions

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to retrieve information from database with submit buttons , which have the same name . I'm giving value which is id of the row , so I could make a different actions, but I can not make up my mind how to do that .

When trying like this for example

```
<form name="form" action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="image" name="x" value="1">

<input type="image" name="x" value="2">
</form>
```

and php =>

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['x'])){
    echo $_POST['x'];
}
?>
```

in chrome it works fine , but in other browsers it doesn't , any ideas ? thanks

**UPDATE**

```
if ($r = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table")){
    if ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<input type='image' name='submit' value='" . $row['id'] . "'>";
        // and other data which I need to
    }
    $r->free();
}
```

I meant like this

Comment: where is the problem taking the different name ?

Comment: why do you want to have the same name for both input ?

Comment: @Mayankswami the problem is that , in chrome when submitting first image , it writes 1, otherwise 2 , but in other browsers it doesn't do anything

Comment: @mgraph like I've explained I'm retrieving data from mysql with submit buttons to do different actions with it's id . if it is possible to do that I have asked

Comment: @Tornike That seems to be a clear indication that using the same name for different inputs might not be the best idea.

Comment: @jeroen I guess this but if anyone have good idea , if it is possible like this I'm interested in

Comment: @Tornike is a JavaScript/jQuery helped answer ok?

Comment: @mgraph I meant that , see update

Comment: *trying to retrieve information from database with submit buttons* is really bad idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="index.php" method="post">
   <input type="button" name="x" value="1">    
   <input type="button" name="x" value="2">
   <input type="text" name="action" id="action">
</form>​
```

​
JavaScript

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('form1').childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {    
    nodes[i].onclick = function(){        
        if(this.name == 'x'){
          document.getElementById('action').value = this.value;
        }
    };
}
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])){

   if($_POST['action'] == "1"){
      ...
   }

   if($_POST['action'] == "2"){
      ...
   }

}
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/qLubz/

Just change `type="text"` to `type="hidden"` when ready to deploy.

Alternatively with no JavaScript:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</button>
</form>​
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="copy">Copy</button>
</form>​
<form action="index.php" method="post">
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="edit">Edit</button>
</form>​
```

Comment: I've fixed problem which I've asked in previous question and has been closed